# How to migrate only Customers from magento 1.x to magento 2.x?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, customer, migration

Actually i want to migrate Customers from magento 1.9 to magento 2.3 if anyone have any idea please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to config file of your magento 1 version.

**Example:**

vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.1/config.xml

Comment everything except this from the data step.

```
<step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
</step>
```

Hope this may help you.

Cheers!!!

Comment: thanks man its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please do the changes in the `data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.1/config.xml`. You can rename the `config.xml.dist` to `config.xml`. You can comment out all other steps except these. Please follow this for detailed instruction https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

```
<steps mode="data">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
</steps>
```

If you want delta migration to be performed(migrating recent data after last migration) please configure this

```
<steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
</steps>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In config.xml File

```
<step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
</step>
```